# Where is struct blkid_struct_dev defined?

Tags: c, util-linux, libblkid

blkid.h typedefs as follows:

```
typedef struct blkid_struct_dev *blkid_dev;
```

That is the only appearance of the token blkid_struct_dev in blkid.h.

```
grep -rl blkid_struct_dev /usr/include
```

returns only /usr/include/blkid/blkid.h. So I'm assuming the struct is defined somewhere in a -dev package I don't have installed (except it doesn't appear anywhere else on my Slackware box, either, and Slackware includes all the headers with its packages).

Where is this struct defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem on my Ubuntu PC and could only find the declaration of the structure. As it turns out, the definition is in a file blkidP.h in the util-linux source. Since only the declarations in blkid.h are needed in order to compile programs using the library, blkidP.h isn't needed. It's only needed to compile the library.